# WebSQL Database Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, synchronization, web-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebSQL Database Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343867/websql-database-upload)

I have a WebSQL database, and am trying to connect to a PHP script, and dump that database into another one on the server.

How do I format the javascript / jquery in order to do that correctly?

I guess I am asking, how do I dump all of my data in my tables into my PHP script, so that it can update and insert the data into another database on the server?

Comment: whoops, can this one be reopened seeing as how they were both started by me and this one has an answer on it?

Answer (score 0):

put all the localStorage or whatever local database you have into a JSON object using js/jQuery/etc., then POST that JSON object, and then using php, go through that POST'ed JSON object and use php code to dump it into your database.

Comment: How would you do that for a database? do `select * from table` and dump the results into a variable which you JSON encode? or how?

Comment: JSON encoding and sending, is done from the browser first. You do an AJAX POST from your browser where you send along the request your packed JSON object. Then you deserialize your JSON in the PHP side, so it turns back into a JS object. Then loop through your object keys/values and then just dump each one into your table. Your table can have same keys and values as in your JS object, e.g.  myjsobject{a:prod1,b:prod2} can lead to table where key a has value prod1 and key b has value prod2. Also if you prefer something else than JSON you can do something like this in the data format you want.